# Calculate the percentage change taking the earliest and last available value for different time series with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I've a time series of poverty values for different countries (countries are in rows, values over time in columns). Unfortunately I've many missing data, but I'd like to calculate the percentage change between the last available year and the earliest available year for each country in Python. So for the ZWE below that would be the pct change between 2019 and 2011 while for ZWB that would be taking 2015 and 2010. Is there a way to automate this? Maybe using iterrows?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

| iso | YR2010 | YR2011 | YR2012 | YR2013 | YR2014 | YR2015 | YR2016 | YR2017 | YR2018 | YR2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZWE | NaN | 22.5 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 30.4 | NaN | 38.3 |
| ZMB | 54.7 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 54.4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Comment: and what would be your expected output? a new column which will show the percentage change?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the related columns to work on by [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), then for each country (each row), drop the `NaN` entries by [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and then divide the last (non-NaN) entry by the first (non-NaN) entry, minus 1 and multiply by 100 to get the percentages:

```
df['% change'] = df.filter(regex=r'YR\d+').apply(lambda x: 0 if len((z:=x.dropna())) == 0 else (z.iloc[-1]/z.iloc[0] -1) * 100, axis=1)
```

or, if your Python version is older than Python 3.8 and does not support the assignment operator `:=`, use:

```
df['% change'] = df.filter(regex=r'YR\d+').apply(lambda x: 0 if len(x.dropna()) == 0 else (x.dropna().iloc[-1]/x.dropna().iloc[0] -1) * 100, axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   iso  YR2010  YR2011  YR2012  YR2013  YR2014  YR2015  YR2016  YR2017  YR2018  YR2019   % change
0  ZWE     NaN    22.5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    30.4     NaN    38.3  70.222222
1  ZMB    54.7     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    54.4     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  -0.548446
```

Comment: Thank you @SeaBean, however I run into an error at ((z:=x.dropna())...

Comment: @sophie395  What's your Python version ?

Comment: @sophie395  Maybe it's because your Python version does not support assignment statement with `:=`  In that case, you can use: `df['% change'] = df.filter(regex=r'YR\d+').apply(lambda x:  (x.dropna().iloc[-1]/x.dropna().iloc[0] -1) * 100, axis=1)`   Same result, but maybe a little bit slower. If your dataset is not too big, should be ok.

Comment: Mm nope, that did not work either, I've got an indexing error (IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds). Running on Running on python 3.7.7

Comment: @sophie395  Then, probably you have some country without values for all years ?  That is, all `NaN` entries for the country ?   In that case, how would you like to handle ?  Not possible for percentage calculation in this case.

Comment: Ahh yes that should be it, so I'd probably have countries without values and with just one: I'd like to skip those

Comment: @sophie395  In that case, you can use:  `df['% change'] = df.filter(regex=r'YR\d+').apply(lambda x: 0 if len(x.dropna()) == 0 else (x.dropna().iloc[-1]/x.dropna().iloc[0] -1) * 100, axis=1)`  This will give 0 for countries with none or only one entry.

Comment: @sophie395  Let me know how it works for you ?

Comment: @sophie395  Any update on your latest test result ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ffill` and `bfill` to get the last and first values respectively, then calculate the percentage change. Example:

```
txt ='''iso YR2010  YR2011  YR2012  YR2013  YR2014  YR2015  YR2016  YR2017  YR2018  YR2019
ZWE NaN 22.5    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 30.4    NaN 38.3
ZMB 54.7    NaN NaN NaN NaN 54.4    NaN NaN NaN NaN'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),sep='\t',index_col=0)

last_indices = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
first_indices = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
percent_change = (last_indices - first_indices)/first_indices *100
print(percent_change)
```

Gives:

```
iso
ZWE    70.222222
ZMB    -0.548446
dtype: float64
```